# Which file location does phpMyAdmin look in?

Tags: php, mysql

For this statement:

```
mysql <my_db_name> -u<user_name> -p<password> <mysql.sql
```

Where does phpMyAdmin assume `mysql.sql` is located in?

Comment: It's a little confusing to use < and > in two entirely different ways in your example. The <> around my_db_name, user_name and password just emphasise that those things are to be replaced with actual values. The last one (in <mysql.sql) is the redirection operator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

regarding gnuds second point:

Reading in a file via < is not specific to mysql.
This works for any command and any file on the commandline.
(on UNIX as well as on Windows):

```
somecommand < somefile
```

data from the file somefile is sent into the command via a channel
called STDIN.

Answer (score 3):

in the directory you are currently located in.

Answer (score 2):

First, this is clearly not about [phpMyAdmin](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/), but about the [mysql](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysql.html) command line tool.

Second, in the command you posted, the `mysql` utility does not look for a file name at all, it reads [stdin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stdin#Standard_input_.28stdin.29) - your shell (like [bash](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) or the windows `cmd`) opens the file and sets it up as the stdin of `mysql`.

Thirdly, all relative filesystem paths (any [path](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_%28computing%29) that doesn't start with a root), are relative to the current working directory.

Comment: Read about redirection at wikipedia, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redirection_%28computing%29 That was a link on the wikipedia page on `stdin`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in the current working directory. but you're not using phpMyAdmin, you're using the `mysql` command.